# How to read PKCS ASN.1 specs

Tags: asn.1

E.g. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208#appendix-A

There is no top level structure defined.   Just a bunch of internal bits that appear in some order.   But where is the outer Sequence?

Also, where does one actually find the imported defenitions, e.g. of Attribute?

Answer (score 2):

There is top level structure, it is `PrivateKeyInfo`:

```
PrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  version Version,
  privateKeyAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier {{PrivateKeyAlgorithms}},
  privateKey PrivateKey,
  attributes [0] Attributes OPTIONAL }
```

> Also, where does one actually find the imported defenitions, e.g. of Attribute?

from ASN.1 module:

```
Attribute
         FROM InformationFramework informationFramework
```

Look for imports:
IMPORTS

```
informationFramework
         FROM UsefulDefinitions {joint-iso-itu-t(2) ds(5) module(1)
                                 usefulDefinitions(0) 3}
```

this stands for OID [1.2.5.1.0.3](http://www.oid-info.com/get/2.5.1.0.3)
InformationFramework is defined in X.501: https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/formal-language/itu-t/x/x501/2019/InformationFramework.html